# how to verify access_token in resource server about oauth2

Tags: node.js, authentication, verify, oauth-2.0

I made resource server and auth server

but I don't understand construction

1.2.  Protocol Flow

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 | Client |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+

 +--------+                                           +---------------+
 |        |--(A)------- Authorization Grant --------->|               |
 |        |                                           |               |
 |        |<-(B)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
 |        |               & Refresh Token             |               |
 |        |                                           |               |
 |        |                            +----------+   |               |
 |        |--(C)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
 |        |                            |          |   |               |
 |        |<-(D)- Protected Resource --| Resource |   | Authorization |
 | Client |                            |  Server  |   |     Server    |
 |        |--(E)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
 |        |                            |          |   |               |
 |        |<-(F)- Invalid Token Error -|          |   |               |
 |        |                            +----------+   |               |
 |        |                                           |               |
 |        |--(G)----------- Refresh Token ----------->|               |
 |        |                                           |               |
 |        |<-(H)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
 +--------+           & Optional Refresh Token        +---------------+
```

I read the oauth2 document

I don't understand,

access_token make be in auth server, this diagram isn't verity way but how does resource server verify it?

Answer (score 0):

How does Resource server verifies the token is outside the scope of the OAuth2 specification. Now for your usecase, You can do following things:
1. Provide introspection endpoint on Authz Server which verifies the authenticity of token and responds back with decoded content of that token
2. Authz Server and Resource server create trust between themselves using certificate mechanism. Here again you have two options:
a. If you want Authz server to be in control then Authz Server can sign the token with private key and Resource server can validate the signature using the public cert provided by AuthzServer
b. Do the opposite, here On Authz server there is provision to upload the certificate for a resource server and Authz server uses that certificate to sign the token and Resource server uses it's private key to validate the content.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to learn more about an actual implementation you can always have a look at Thinktecture's code : https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/source

They implement a complete system which is then used by a lot of people who need OAuth2 system. I have an article on the subject as well, which you're welcome to check it out : https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/

Comment: thanks. I got it. I want to how to know verity check about light traffic. some people said. if you want verify token. you always request AS. but this case It make be heavy traffic to the AS. so I guess if I use the jwt than it reduce traffic. finally I make be sure by your opinion.